# AsyncTask nested calls

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Supposing I'm using the following `AsycTask` (called **A**) for sending data over internet:

```
private class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Notification", "Sending message...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendMessage();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();           
    }
}
```

Inside the `doInbackground` is called the my method sendMessage(). I will not go into details of this method, just immagine that this method executes a `Thread` (suppouse that it is called `B`).

So, the question is:

The code inside the `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask` **A** will be executed after the end of the `Thread` **B**?

If not, how can make possible that the onPostExecute will be executed only when the `AsyncTask` inside the sendMessage() will be terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could let the `sendMessage()` return the Thread object and then call

```
Thread.join()
```

This will cause the `doInBackground` to wait until the thread is finished.

Comment: You are right, I was just sperimienting join() method, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is pretty simple. Just call that `AsyncTask` **B** in `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` **A**.

**Edit** : Thread inside thread is not possible from ICS onwards. It will not give you any error, but it will not work too and your app will stuck there.

Comment: Obvious @Ravi, but mine is a theoretical question

Comment: mate, can you please post a link or somethink. I want to know details about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bluebrain I don't have a link for it but If you look at the working style of `AsyncTask` then you get that the answer is pretty simple.